# How do I use Blazor [Parameter] attribute in a component?

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor

Using the `[Parameter]` attribute on a variable in a Razor component in a Razor Class Library errors out when I use it.

The error I get is:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type 'DashboardComponents.LineGraph' does not have a property matching the name 'Values'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'DashboardComponents.LineGraph' does not have a property matching the name 'Values'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForUnknownIncomingParameterName(Type targetType, String parameterName)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object target)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
```

But I'm not sure why it says there is no property matching `Values` since it's defined right in the LineGraph.razor.cs file:

```cs
namespace DashboardComponents;

public partial class LineGraph
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public static List<double> Values { get; set; } = new();


    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public static double Scale { get; set; }


    [Parameter] 
    public static double GraphWidth { get; set; } = 500;

    [Parameter]
    public static double GraphHeight { get; set; } = 300;

    [Parameter] public ComponentColors Colors { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And where I'm testing it in another Blazor WASM project, it is used like this:

```
@page "/"
@using DashboardComponents

<LineGraph Values="@Values" Scale="5" />

@code {
    private readonly List<double> Values = new()
    {
        0,
        7,
        5.5,
        3.4,
        9
    };
}
```

I've tried changing the variable name around, using `@Value` in the testing razor file, using the different `[Parameter]` types, but nothing wants to work.

Comment: The `Parameter` attribute cannot be used on static properties

Comment: Oh, my god.. Thanks for that, I really feel like that should be pointed out in IDE but I digress. Add this as an answer and I'll accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `[Parameter]` attribute on a static property. All properties should be non-static.

```cs
// this
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public static List<double> Values { get; set; } = new();
// would become
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public List<double> Values { get; set; } = new();
```